# check if a file is a unix file and set a bit if it's true

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to create a shell file that looks for whether a file is a Unix or a Dos file type. Using an IF query I want to decide after checking whether the file needs to be converted using "dos2unix" or not. I know the command "FILE" but the return value is no BOOLEAN data type its a string.

So is there any way to set a BOOLEAN bit to true if the file is a unix file type?

thanks in advance...!

Comment: you can use `if file ${myfile} |grep -q  'ASCII text' ;then bool=1 ;else bool=0 ;fi`

Comment: Maybe `dos2unix`'s option `-ic` can be used, see `man dos2unx`  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dos2unix.1.html Citation: *Convert only files that have DOS line breaks and leave the other files untouched: `dos2unix -ic *.txt | xargs dos2unix`*. `dos2unix` should not change a file that already has UNIX line endings, so it does not hurt to run it on all files.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick replies. i will try it with the dos2unix -ic option because in my case it really doesn't matter to run it on all files.

Comment: Unix can store all file types, not just ones without CR-LF, so there's not really a *"Unix file"* type. Maybe you should use a variable called *"DopeyWindowsThing"* 

Comment: @PS: This would not work, because the description printed by `file` contains the string  _ASCII text_  for all text files, irrespective of the line ending.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for correcting, It was untested solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the output of the `file` command. For text files with \n line endings, it outputs `ASCII text ...`, while for text files with \r\n line endings, it outputs `ASCII text ... with CRLF line terminators`. Note that depending on the actual file contents, there can be additional information in place of the "...". Hence, you could do something like

```
file YOURFILE | grep -q '^ASCII text.*with CRLF'
((is_dos_text_file=1-$?))
```

The variable `is_dos_text_file` contains the value 1, if YOURFILE was judged by file as a text file with CRLF endings. It is 0 if YOURFILE either has Unix line endings, or was not judged as textfile.

UPDATE: I just noticed that you have used the *shell* tag in your posting and hence search for a Posix Shell solution. In this case, the `((...))` construct can't be used and you would have to do something like

```
if file YOURFILE | grep -q '^ASCII text.*with CRLF'
then
  is_dos_text_file=1 # true
else
  is_dos_text_file=0 # false
fi
```

to get the same effect.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I have implemented it according to your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the file to a Unix file and check if it is still the same. In that case it is a Unix file. Otherwise it is a DOS file.

```
echo unix > unix-file
echo dos | unix2dos > dos-file

for file in {dos,unix}-file; do
  if cmp -s $file <(dos2unix < $file); then
    echo $file is a unix file
  else
    echo $file is a dos file
  fi
done
```

Comment: Only for ascii files, do not perform `dos2unix /bin/cp`.

Comment: And don't look in the sun with a telescope.